# rxjs switchMap not working in Angular Guard?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router-guards, switchmap

```
return this.auth.user.pipe(
      switchMap((user: IUser) => {
        return of(true);
      })
    );
```

My initial code was a bit more complex with some cases depending on the user data, but for testing purposes I've used the code above in a guard's canLoad and it does not activate.

There's TS/compilation errors whatsoever.

I've tried it both with Ivy and without.

I'm using Angular 8.3;

Comment: please write the error

Comment: @KhashayarPakkhesal there's no error, the route doesn't activate. I've added a catchError operator just to be safe and there's no error either.

I've checked to see if that code runs inside the switchMap and it does, if I log something on the console there it will show up when I try to activate the route.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use a `take(1)`, because I'm sure the `auth.user` is a stream and does not complete. A guard needs to have a completing Observable:

```
return this.auth.user.pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap((user: IUser) => of(!!user))
);
```

Perhaps you removed some code, but you can also just use map here:

```
return this.auth.user.pipe(
  take(1),
  map((user: IUser) => !!user)
);
```

Comment: Never completes or maybe never emits. Both would stop it from loading.

Comment: This works -- I did not know the guard needs a completing observable. Thanks a bunch!